# A word for a large underground library

Tags: synonyms

I am looking for a word to describe a large underground library many times the height of an average person. The word "edifice" means a large, imposing, and important building. However, I feel like this word does not imply that the library is underground. Does anyone know of any better words to describe this library?

Comment: *The Cave of Forgotten Call Numbers* or *The Dewey Decimal Deep*.

Comment: What about “***the book cellar***”?

Comment: @Jim I feel like cellar bears too much resemblance to basement: planking, stonework, and ambient dripping water or musty air. The library I have in mind is more of a tech-infused place that has an atmosphere similar to air conditioning, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Symantra - it was more of a tongue-in-cheek pun suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cavernous carrell

A buried bibliotheca

A subterranean study

Or my fav

The [sunken](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/underground) [stacks](http://www.synonym.com/synonyms/stacks)

> stacks (n.)
>
> storage space in a library consisting of an extensive arrangement of bookshelves where most of the books are stored
>
> Synonyms:
>
> depository, storage space, library
>
> [synonym.com: stacks](http://www.synonym.com/synonyms/stacks)

Comment: Cavernous carrel and buried bibliotheca are a bit too florid, but I agree with @alwayslearning. Subterranean study has a nice ring to it!